# Get passed element properties and attributes without many jQuery requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

I have some list with list elements, which each of them have many custom attributes, like `data-user-id`, `data-avatar` and so on. On each list element I am attaching a jQuery click event like this

```
$('*.friendListItem').on('click', function () {
    var userId = this.something;
    var avatar = this.foo;
}
```

Now since I have the passed element with all of its properties and attributes I need in the `this` object, I am looking for the most optimal way to access them, since doing it with `$(this).attr('data-user-id);` would result in unneccessary DOM traversions.

The only way I can think of now using pure Javascript is like this

```
this.attributes['data-user-id'].nodeValue
```

which doesn't seem good and optimal.

Is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Element.dataSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

```
var userId = this.dataset.userId; //data-user-id
```

Note: For Hyphenated properties *camelCase* will be used.

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  console.log(this.dataset.userId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-user-id="10">Click me<span>
```

Comment: meh, I could've found that with a little bit more debugging, thanks :) will mark as answer